# Can I use a Variable to access the property name of an object?

Tags: php

Let's assume I have the following...

`$current_user->ID = 3;`

Let's also assume I have the following...

`$read = $recipient->read_3;`

Note that that the number in the `$recipient->read_` property name can change so I don't actually know there is a `$recipient->read_3;`. I want get the name (e.g. `3`) from the value of `$current_user->ID` to add to `$recipient->read_` to get the correct property name.

How do I do that?

I would love to do this...
`$read = $recipient->read_$current_user->ID;` but that is not correct... What is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can save it in a variable and use it. Here is an example:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->read_3 = '3';
$id = 3;
$read = 'read_'.$id;
echo $object->$read;
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @majed-badawi I came up with the following:

`$num = "read_".$current_user->ID;`

`$read = $recipient->$num;`

Comment: please mark the answer as the solution to close the question.

Comment: It is ok to post you own answer, but you should consider accepting/upvoting the helpful answers that got you there :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use try using **PHP variable variables**. These let you create dynamic variables so you can do this:

```
$propname = "read_".$current_user->ID;
$read = $recipient->{$propname};
```

You can find out more about variable variables here: [PHP.net variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)